# Google Data Studio RegExp_Match not matching textPayload dimension in log payload

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm new to Google Data Studio, and currently stuck on the following problem.
I have some log data in BigQuery and I am trying to visualize some info out of my logs using Google Data Studio.

The problem is when I use `REGEXP_MATCH` on one specific dimension of my data, it cannot match the RegEx. When I use `REGEXP_MATCH` against any other dimension of my log data, it works without a problem.

I am wondering, whether that could be due to the long strings that I have in that specific dimension, or are there any other thoughts?

By the way, I am able to make changes to that dimension using `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but cannot even do `REGEXP_MATCH`  against the text that `REGEXP_REPLACE` replaced in there.

I have been working around this for days now and any advise will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that `REGEXP_EXTRACT` works against that dimension. Then it's also possible to do `REGEXP_MATCH` on the output of `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with no problem.

I still don't know why `REGEXP_MATCH` does not work directly against that specific  dimension, maybe due to long strings or some specific letters that I have in my data in that dimension or some other reason.